# iOS Background Mode: After running location updates in the background, the app never terminates

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm running location updates in the background. All works well:

- On significant location the app is launched in the background

`- appDidFinishLaunching(options:)` is called as expected.

- I start `LocationManager startUpdatingLocation()` and `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`
- Locations are collected correctly.
- After some time, I call `stopUpdatingLocation()`
- My program at this stage doesn't need to do anything and no further code is executed

At this point the program stays idle. `applicationWillTerminate` is never called again. Is this expected? I'd hoped the app will shut down again as no location updates are required.

What's the expected behaviour? Should the app shut down or should it stay idle forever?

Once this happens, then if a user user opens the app or a significant location is received again, then `appDidFinishLaunching(options:)` is NOT called, but instead `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Is there any documentation I can follow that supports the expected behaviour?

Comment: Do you terminate the app for calling 'applicationWillTerminate ' ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, everything here is expected. There's a deleted answer from J.D. Wooder that correctly linked the documentation: ["Managing Your App's Life Cycle."](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle) As a rule, background iOS apps are not proactively killed. They are only killed when system resources are needed. This is unpredictable, and the app typically will not receive a `applicationWillTerminate` message when it happens (because the app typically is not running at that point, and it won't be woken up just to kill it). Your app should handled both a cold launch (`appDidFinishLaunching`) and a warm launch (`applicationDidBecomeActive`).

Restarting an app from scratch is expensive, so iOS prefers to keep recently used thing in memory if there's no resource pressure. Apps that are doing nothing are very cheap. to keep around.

Note that iOS 13 has grown much more aggressive in killing apps in the background, and that the large cameras on new phones are leading to memory pressures that kill apps more quickly as well, so don't get too comfortable with running in the background for a long time. But it's also very normal.

Comment: See the section "Respond to App-Based Life-Cycle Events," and the links in that section. Particularly note the picture there showing how the app life-cycle works prior to iOS 13 (it's slightly different in 13, but pretty similar)

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to be there. Deleted it. I found the link and edited your answer.

Comment: @RobNapier why then for example here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html stated that "At wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location services and process the location data."?

Comment: @daleijn I don't understand the question. You are generally given a small amount of time, and then suspended. You're generally are not terminated unless you violate the protocol (by not handling expiration events, for example).

Comment: @RobNapier please, can you see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718821/why-app-awakened-by-uiapplicationlaunchoptionskey-location-never-get-killed-in

Comment: @daleijn That looks identical to this question. It is very rare for the app to be terminated. It is completely normal for it to just be awakened.

Comment: @RobNapier It is completely normal for it to just be awakened for unpredictable time, and when the system decides that it needs more resources it'll kill the app? So, is the meaning of that quote that I gave is: system guarantee 10 second of execution at least, and after that it may be killed, or maybe not and can live for hours? Because I thought that after 10 sec it must be killed by the system mandatory,

Comment: --"It is completely normal for it to just be awakened for unpredictable time, and when the system decides that it needs more resources it'll kill the app?" Yes. Exactly. -- "system guarantee 10 second of execution at least." No. You are promised "a small amount of time (around 10 seconds)." -- "and after that it may be killed, or maybe not and can live for hours?" Correct. -- "after 10 sec it must be killed by the system mandatory." No.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the iOS app [Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle),

```
appDidFinishLaunching will call only when app Launch,
applicationWillTerminate  - called when app terminate from background
applicationDidBecomeActive - Called when app comes to foreground from background
```

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is rarely actually called when an app is terminated from the background. If the app is suspended (which is common), then it will not be woken up just to be terminated; it'll just be terminated silently.